# How do I debug my responsive email newsletter template?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, gmail, html-email, newsletter

Essentially, I need a way to debug my email on mobile. Everything looks great, the layout is perfect, until I allow images (in my case, Gmail `Allow Images` button at the top of the email). At this point all formatting is lost and `td`'s begin to overlap, some images scale up absurdly high, some scale down. The floats do not work after allowing images as well.

I started with Zurb University's email templates (you may find them [here:](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates) ), again, everything works great in browser but when i actually open up chrome or safari and open the email, the formatting is broken in the exact same way every time.

So, I am asking if anyone knows of a way to debug emails. Or requesting to learn more about other known problems with the `Allow Images` button breaking the layout of an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is more than likely your CSS. For instance float is not supported in pretty much all email clients. On top of that, you need to make the actual dimensions of the images match what you want them to be in email. Without a sample of what you are using, I cannot give much more.

Also Using HTML or CSS to resize is unreliable.

Best cost effective email testing tool in my opinion is [Email On Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/).

Comment: Hello there, Thank you so much for answering my question!

Basically, I dealt with your feedback by removing any html or css I had that was resizing image elements. And this worked to some extent. Rather than white space on either side of the email and images extending past the content container, I am now seeing a shrunken version of my email on mobile. Hooray!

As far as actual responsive capabilities it is certainly not all there. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a viewport tag may help solve this issue. See this for more info - http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_viewport_metatag_rendered_unusable